# Delphi silently cropping string literals

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Delphi 2009 Win32.

The code below tries to add a 257 length string to a memo.
It compiles and runs fine, but nothing is added to the memo.

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
```

Looks like a compiler bug. Is it? Because if the string was 256 long, I'd get a compiler error and couldn't compile the app.

Any way to make the app break when the developer tries to do something like this?

I know I could split the string and make this code work, but my point is to prevent developers for using this invalid code without noticing.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a Delphi 2009 bug with string literals, it should raise the same error as D2007.

Try latest version of Andreas IDE Fix pack, its supose to fix this bug.
http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=246

Comment: And Andreas keep fixing Delphi over and over. :)

Comment: Yes, Andreas is dong a great job!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Gamecat, however if your dealing with a string that large, I would break it
into muliple lines to assist in reading/editing.

if you are LITTERALLY trying to create 257 "a"'s then why not use the DupeString function in the StrUtils unit?

```
Memo.Lines.Add( DupeString('a',257) );
```

Much easier to read, and maintain later.  If you are doing this in a loop and therefore are worried about performance, then assign the function result to a local variable and use the variable.

```
var
  sLotsOfAs : string;
  ix : integer;
begin
  sLotsOfAs := DupeString('a',257);
  for ix := 0 to 1000000 do
    Memo.Lines.Add( sLotsOfAs );
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The string literal can be only 255 characters long. Not sure why they kept this limitation. But you can solve it using multiple literals:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('i have 128 chars' + 'i also have 128 chars').
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about D2009, but under Delphi 6 at least, string literals are limited to 255 characters, and the compiler diagnoses the error.

Comment: I believe the 255 limit is due to Delphi (pre-D2009 anyway) storing the length in the first byte of the string buffer. I.e. string[0] is the length, and being a byte it can store 0-255.

Comment: All versions of Delphi since Delphi 2 have supported long string variables and are not limited to 255 characters. Except, it seems, for string literals!

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 2007, I get:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(29): E2056 String literals may have at most 255 elements
```

In Delphi 5, I get:

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(29): String literals may have at most 255 elements
```

If the D2009 behavior is as you describe, then two things come to mind:

1 - They expanded the limit on the # of chars in a string, but the TMemo can still only **accept** up to 255.

or

2 - It's a plain old bug

As far as preventing it, the only thing I can think of is to make a regex to search for these strings in your .PAS files.

Comment: In light of the answer from Cesar Romero... do you have the IDE Fix pack installed?

Comment: I doubt that he has the 2.6 Beta 1 installed because this one is brand new and wasn't available to public until Cesar Romero posted the link here.